# Panel Header covering the grid when I change its height - ExtJS

Tags: css, image, extjs, header

Here's my issue. I added a picture into the Header Panel and the I wanted to change the height  the Panel.

I did all of this via my CSS File :

```
.x-panel-header-default {
   background-image: url('../image/wall.png') !important;
   height: 100px;
}
```

It works but then the grid doesn't scale automatically, it results with the Header Panel going over the cells of my grids, like this

```
Panel Header
Panel Header
Grid Header   <- hiding the panel header
Panel Header  <- hiding the grid cells
Grid Cells
Grid Cells
...
```

I hope I was clearest as possible :)
Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For a background image re-sizing, you can use [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) property. However, this is not supported by IE7/8. For managing the height of the panel, you can use % values or set @media queries.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer but I don't want to resize a picture, I want to resize the Panel Header without having it overlaying the grid columns.